# Java: How to remove xmlns from DOM element?

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c

Collegues, can't find decision for my problem...

This is my code which add `SngtrSt` element to `Envlp`:

```
SupplementaryDataEnvelope1 supplementaryDataEnvelope1 = new SupplementaryDataEnvelope1();
//Adding SplmtryData
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
//doc.setDocumentURI("urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03");
Element sngtrStElement = doc.createElement("SngtrSt");
sngtrStElement.setTextContent(TranConstants.SNGTR_ST_VALUE);
//sngtrStElement.removeAttributeNS("urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03", "xmlns");
supplementaryDataEnvelope1.setAny(sngtrStElement);
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03">
    <AcctRptgReq>
          ...
            <SplmtryData>
                <Envlp>
                    <SngtrSt xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03">  </SngtrSt>
                </Envlp>
            </SplmtryData>
    </AcctRptgReq>
</Document>
```

How to avoid adding string `xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03"` to `SngtrSt` element (remove xmlns with its value from element)?

Comment: Although you haven't shown it, my guess is that the parent element Envlp is in a namespace, and the xmlns="" undeclaration is needed because you have created a child element that is in no namespace. The namespace undeclaration will disappear if you create the child element in the same namespace as its parent.

Comment: @Michael Kay , I add root element with namespace.

Comment: @May12 - So you want doc.createElementNS("urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.060.001.03", "SngtrSt");